# Python all possible group combinations of teams with different sizes

Tags: python, grouping, combinations

I am trying to form every unique possible set of teams, of different sizes, from a group of people. I have a list of people of size n and there are k teams. In the case below there are 13 people and 4 teams.

`people = ["Bob", "Jane", "Mary", "Martha", "James", "Charles", "Kevin", "Debbie", "Brian", "Matt", "Milo", "Chris", "Sam"]`

example output:

```
[[Bob, Jane, Mary], [Martha, James, Charles], [Kevin, Debbie, Brian], [Matt, Milo, Chris, Sam]]
[[Bob, Jane, Mary], [Martha, James, Charles], [Kevin, Debbie, Matt], [Brian, Milo, Chris, Sam]]
[[Bob, Jane, Mary], [Martha, James, Charles], [Kevin, Debbie, Milo], [Brain, Matt, Chris, Sam]]
[[Bob, Jane, Mary], [Martha, James, Charles], [Kevin, Debbie, Chris], [Brian, Matt, Milo, Sam]]
.
.
.
[[Bob, Jane, Mary], [Martha, James, Charles], [Kevin, Debbie, Brian, Matt], [Milo, Chris, Sam]]
.
.
.
```

Teams can be any size 3 - 5. I have seen similar versions of this problem but none with the addition that teams can vary in size. The result I'm hoping for is implemented in such a way that I can call a function that takes in the set of teams and returns an integer as a score for the team and keeps track of the team with the highest score.

ie:

```
def generate_best_teams(people, num_teams):
    loop:
        teams gets created
        teams_score = calculate_score(teams)
        if teams_score > best_score:
            best_score = teams_score
            best_teams = teams

    return best_teams
```

Any help with this problem would be greatly apricated.

Comment: Some thoughts: I guess that the order of teams doesn't matter (e. g. switching first and second team will produce same score, teams lists are equivalent). If so, "Bob" is always in the first team (I call it team 0). Then you should go through people list and assign a team to each one. One rule is that the highest available team number is the highest used team number plus one. This means that "Jane" can only have 0 or 1. This prevents the mentioned equivalent teams lists. The remaining is a recursive backtracking which considers the different constraints on the team choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to make a generator to produce the result. I'm pretty sure there is better way to do it. See if it works:

```py
from itertools import permutations, islice, product

def length_to_split(n, min_teammate, max_teammate):
    '''Return a list of pattern, e.g.

    >>> length_to_split(13, 3, 5)
    [(3, 5, 5), (4, 4, 5), (3, 3, 3, 4)]
    '''
    min_number_of_group = n // max_teammate + 1
    max_number_of_group = n // min_teammate

    result = []
    for i in range(min_number_of_group, max_number_of_group + 1):
        for x in list(product(*([range(min_teammate, max_teammate + 1)] * i))):
            if sum(x) == n and list(x) == sorted(x):
                result.append(x)
    return result

def team_generator(people, min_teammate, max_teammate):
    '''Loop through all permutation then remove duplicate.'''
    n = len(people)
    patterns = length_to_split(n, min_teammate, max_teammate)
    for p in patterns:
        for comb in permutations(range(n), n):
            input = iter(comb)
            comb = [list(islice(input, elem)) for elem in p]
            
            # Remove duplicate permutation
            for sublist in comb:
                if sublist != sorted(sublist):
                    break
            else:
                comb = [[people[i] for i in t] for t in comb]
                yield comb

# Testing
people = ["Bob", "Jane", "Mary", "Martha", "James", "Charles", "Kevin", "Debbie", "Brian", "Matt", "Milo", "Chris", "Sam"]
min_teammate = 3
max_teammate = 5

g = team_generator(range(13), min_teammate, max_teammate)
for i in range(3):
    print(next(g))

print()

g = team_generator(people, min_teammate, max_teammate)
for i in range(3):
    print(next(g))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 8], [7, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 9], [7, 8, 10, 11, 12]]

[['Bob', 'Jane', 'Mary'], ['Martha', 'James', 'Charles', 'Kevin', 'Debbie'], ['Brian', 'Matt', 'Milo', 'Chris', 'Sam']]
[['Bob', 'Jane', 'Mary'], ['Martha', 'James', 'Charles', 'Kevin', 'Brian'], ['Debbie', 'Matt', 'Milo', 'Chris', 'Sam']]
[['Bob', 'Jane', 'Mary'], ['Martha', 'James', 'Charles', 'Kevin', 'Matt'], ['Debbie', 'Brian', 'Milo', 'Chris', 'Sam']]
```

Edited: fixed some typos in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you got like here 13 people, you used teams of three until you need a team of four for the other people. Now you have to create an algorithm that will create teams in a size of three to five. I think this variation of members per team is for the problem that the people can't fit in teams of like three. I would create teams of three until I need teams of four or five. Also you can create all teams in all sizes but this is for a higher number of people too much teams.